# ResultSetExtractorException in SQL-Interpolation

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I'm facing some issues with [**SQL-Interpolation**](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/sql-interpolation.html) in `ScalikeJdbc`. Upon trying to run following piece of code

```
val dbTableSQLSyntax: SQLSyntax = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(dbTableName)

sql"""
   SELECT
     COUNT(*) AS count,
     MIN($distributionColumn) AS min,
     MAX($distributionColumn) AS max
   FROM
     $dbTableSQLSyntax
 """.stripMargin.
  map(mapResult).
  single().
  apply().
  get()
```

I get this error

```
scalikejdbc.ResultSetExtractorException: Failed to retrieve value because For input string: "tab_id". If you're using SQLInterpolation, you may mistake u.id for u.resultName.id.
    at scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet.wrapIfError(WrappedResultSet.scala:27)
    at scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet.get(WrappedResultSet.scala:479)
    at scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet.longOpt(WrappedResultSet.scala:233)
...
```

---

- How can I get rid of this error without having to use [**Query-DSL**](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/query-dsl.html)?
- Is there anything I can improve upon (in terms of performance / security) in above *code-snippet*?

---

Frameworks / Libraries

- `Scala 2.11.11`
- `"org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.2.0"`

---

**EDIT-1**

In response to **@Kazuhiro Sera**'s answer, I'm providing my `mapResult` method

```
def mapResult(rs: WrappedResultSet): (Long, Long, Long) = {
  val count: Long = rs.long("count")
  val minOpt: Option[Long] = rs.longOpt("min")
  val maxOpt: Option[Long] = rs.longOpt("max")
  (count, minOpt.getOrElse(0), maxOpt.getOrElse(Long.MaxValue))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your `mapResult` function. I am afraid that `mapResult` tries to fetch `tag_id` from the ResultSet value. In this case, your SQL query returns only `count`, `min`, and `max`.

Comment: I was probably dreaming then: the exception couldn't have been clearer: `..because For input string: "tab_id"..`. Indeed there's a column called `tab_id` in my `MySQL` table; I must've used a different `mapResult` method at the time (of posting question) / wrongly `aliased` the column in `SQL`-query.